# After CoreData lightweight migration not able to save data in new attribute added

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I am working with CoreData and I am doing lightweight migration where a new attribute is added to an Entity. The migration process is working fine.. the new attribute is added and old data is intact. But the problem is new xcdatamodeld version is showing newly added attribute that is blank. When I add new data to the attribute, the data is not stored.
Here is the code I am adding to the app delegate where the persistent container object is being created :

```
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myAppName")
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions =  [description]
```

migration is happening properly but data from old data model is not shown in my tableview and new data that I add to the database have no persistence.

Comment: can you please elaborate it and please provide some code.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @ HaZa yes!! It was just some code placement issue in my case.